# PDO PHP, подготовленный запрос и регулярные выражения

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

передаю в функцию параметр и хочу использовать его в регулярном выражении, но этот код не работает и не выдает ошибок. Eсли вместо `':code%'` пишу `'$code%'`, т.е. просто передаю переменную, то код выполняется как должен. Хочу использовать именно подготовленный запрос. Подскажите правильный синтаксис.

```
function codeFindPart($code)
{
  //...
  $sql="SELECT code_1
        FROM fkko_id
        WHERE code_1 LIKE ':code%' ";

  $result=$pdo->prepare($sql);
  $result->bindParam(":code",$code,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $result->execute();
  //...
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На уровне запроса тоже не проблема, необходимо только учитывать что PDO подставляет самодостаточный параметр, т.е. у вас будет кусочек текста. Вот к тексту и надо приклеить символ `%`, для чего есть функция `concat`:

```
WHERE code_1 LIKE concat(:code, '%')
```

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то, что надо)

Answer (score 2):

Меняйте не запрос, а саму передаваемую переменную.

```
function codeFindPart($code)
{
    //...
    $sql="SELECT code_1
        FROM fkko_id
        WHERE code_1 LIKE :code ";

    $result=$pdo->prepare($sql);
    $result->bindParam(":code", "$code%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->execute();
    //...
}
```

Почитайте [тут](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo#like), полезно.

Comment: тоже  хорошее решение, благодарю